# Place an Image scaled at the width available space

Tags: codenameone

I created a code that works, but I'm not sure that it's the best way to place an `Image` scaled automatically to the available width space. I need to put some content over that image, so I have a `LayeredLayout`: in the first layer there is the `Label` created with the following code, on the second layer there is a `BorderLayout` that has the same size of the Image.

Is the following code fine or is it possible to do better?

```
Label background = new Label(" ", "NoMarginNoPadding") {
            boolean onlyOneTime = false;

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                int labelWidth = this.getWidth();
                int labelHeight = labelWidth * bgImage.getHeight() / bgImage.getWidth();
                this.setPreferredH(labelHeight);
                if (!onlyOneTime) {
                    onlyOneTime = true;
                    this.getParent().revalidate();
                }
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };
        background.getAllStyles().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT);
        background.getAllStyles().setBgImage(bgImage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter code:

```
ScaleImageLabel sl = new ScaleImageLabel(bgImage);
sl.setUIID("Container");
```

You shouldn't override paint to set the preferred size. You should have overriden `calcPreferredSize()`. For `ScaleImageLabel` it's already set to the natural size of the image which should be pretty big.